# Require local image downloaded with react-native-fetch-blob

Tags: image, react-native, require, react-native-fetch-blob

I’m trying to require an image downloaded with react-native-fetch-blob in my Image component, but when I give it the image path it keeps saying me « Unknow named module: ‘/Users/…/Library/…’

What is the right way to require images stored in a local directory ?

```
let imagePath = null

RNFetchBlob
  .config({
     fileCache : true
  })
  .fetch('GET', uri)
  // the image is now dowloaded to device's storage
  .then((resp) => {
     // the image path you can use it directly with Image component
     imagePath = resp.path()
     this.setState({ uri: require(imagePath) })

     try {
       AsyncStorage.setItem(`${this.props.uri}`, imagePath);
     } catch (error) {
       console.log(error)
     }
  })
```

My render method :

```
render() {
    return(
      <Image style={this.props.style} source={this.state.uri} />
    )
}
```

The problem is not because I set a variable as source because it's working when I put something like : `this.setState({ uri: require('../images/test.jpg') })` after my download.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`require(imagePath)` exists to help packager to find local images and place them to application bundle.

When you need to show dynamically loaded image, you simple need to pass `file` location as URI, for ex:

```
render() {
  const imageAbsolutePath = this.state.imagePath;
  const imageUri = 'file://' + imageAbsolutePath;
  return <Image source={{uri: imageUri}}/>;
}
```

So, you shold not need any `require` statements in this case.

Comment: I need to show the images with absolute path in ListView item. When i do this in listviewItem, It throws error ExceptionsManager.js:73 The RCTURLRequestHandlers <RCTDataRequestHandler: 0x6040000062a0> and <RCTBlobManager: 0x600000449cc0> both reported that they can handle the request <NSMutableURLRequest: 0x6040002034d0> { URL: /Users/apple/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0D5D7EF6-DD5E-4EB3-8B54-4E7970099F17/data/Containers/Data/Applicati ... rews.png }, and have equal priority (0). This could result in non-deterministic behavior. How can I resolve this. Please help.